# Getting Active sheet index number in excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the index number of whatever sheet I put a formula into.

I am very new to VBA, however have tried a simple forumla:

```
Function ACTIVESHEET(number)
    ACTIVESHEET = ACTIVESHEET.Index
End Function
```

And then in an excel cell:

```
=ACTIVESHEET
```

Which returns only #NAME . Maybe I need an input for the function (ie this sheet), but I'm not sure what to put.

I have tried an alternate VBA formula

```
Function ACTIVESHEET(number)
    Return ACTIVESHEET.Index
End Function
```

However that is erronous.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, it is as simple as using =SHEET() in Excel!

The related questions had the answer. Thanks anyway!